# How to debug the Whook's `E_NOT_FOUND` error?

Tags: rest, http, server

I have the `E_NOT_FOUND` error but can't manage to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

The `E_NOT_FOUND` error means the router could not find any declared route in the API definition you provided.

Several possibilities :

- the route simply doesn't exists (easy to fix: create it if needed)
- the handler definition is not declared in the API service : per default handlers definitions are automatically loaded by [the `API_DEFINITIONS` service](https://github.com/nfroidure/whook/blob/master/packages/whook/src/services/API_DEFINITIONS.ts), you can get some informations on what it does by running your server with debug traces: `DEBUG=whook npm run dev`
- the router cannot match the route for some reasons: you can inspect how the [`siso` router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/siso) tries to match you request with its registered paths by running `DEBUG=siso npm run dev`
- finally, you can get an overview of the final API declaration by printing your Open API declaration : `npx whook inspect --name="API" --pretty`